# Функция выдает ошибку

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Функция из скрипта на проверку правильности введенных в форму регистрации данных выдает ошибку там, где вводится адрес электронной почты.

```
function validateEmail(field) {
        if (field == "") {return "Не введен адрес электронной почты.\n"}
        else if (!((field.indexOf(".") > 0) && (field.indexOf("@") > 0)) || /[^a-zA-Z0-9.@_-]/.test(field)) 
            {return "Адрес электронной почты имеет неверный формат.\n"}
        return ""
    }
```

Адрес, например, 123df@mail.ru, будет ошибочным, браузер выдаст: Адрес электронной почты имеет неверный формат
Что не так? Это из книжки пример

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте вот такой регекс для проверки валидности почты:

```
/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}$/i
```

В вашем по крайней мере не хватает плюса в конце.
Кроме того, если судить по вашему регулярному в целом, адрес допускает значение вида `"asdf@lkj@lkj@.s"`.

```
function validateEmail(field) {
    field = field.toLowerCase();
    if (field == "") { return "Не введен адрес электронной почты.\n"}
    else if (!(/^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,6}$/.test(field)))  
        {return "Адрес электронной почты имеет неверный формат.\n"}
    return ""
}
```

Comment: А чё т всё равно ругается.

Comment: Это из книжки пример, я только учусь. С плюсом да, дело пошло.

Comment: @Heidel, поправил код, попробуйте.

Comment: @krem4ik, Вы не доверяете своей же регулярке? Зачем вот это  

    field.indexOf(".") > 0) && (field.indexOf("@") > 0))
Если строка соответствует этому шаблону, то в ней по-любому точка и собака присутствуют.

Comment: @ReinRau, да, действительно) какой бред получился) исправил. Спасибо :)

Comment: А теперь в случае соответствия шаблона возвращает ошибку, а в случае несоответствия что все ок :)

Comment: Да, чё-то я совсем дурной) добавил восклицание)

Comment: Вот теперь все ок :)

Comment: Вообще-то, вот это 
    (!/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}$/.test(field)) снова выдает ошибку

Comment: Да, действительно. Исправил и проверил)

Comment: Перед  

    Не введен адрес электронной по
return пропущен

Comment: Да, вот так всё работает, спасибо!